# Const array initalize from other const array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const char DICTIONARY[][6] = {
    "apple",
    "sands"
};

class LetterSet {
    public:
        unsigned int bitfield;
        LetterSet(const char letters[5]) {};
};

const LetterSet words[] = {
    LetterSet(DICTIONARY[0]),
    LetterSet(DICTIONARY[1]),
};
```

How can I modify the code above to work in the case where `DICTIONARY` is too large to feasibly write out by hand? Specifically, I do not understand how to initalize the `words` array in any way that is not a runtime loop-through and create each element.

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` and `std::array` / `std::vector` ? Is it on purpose that `const char letters[5]` has no room for the null terminator?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, this is ultimately part of a project related to wordle and I am dealing with words that are strictly 5 characters long

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number re: nonuse of `std::string` and `std:array`, it's just because I'm not very familiar with cpp. I chose not to use `std::string` because my dictionary has a well-defined max length, and I didn't use `std::array` because I didn't see any reason it would be better, but I admit that is possibly due to ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be needed by Carson, but for those looking for a way to transform an array elements to another type at compile time, it's possible using helper templates and `std::array`. An example:

```
template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
auto transform_array_impl(auto&& array, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    {{
        T(array[Is])...
    }};
}

template<class T, class U, std::size_t N>
auto transform_array(const U (&array)[N])
{
    return transform_array_impl<T>(array, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

const auto words = transform_array<LetterSet>(DICTIONARY);
```

Comment: Very neat. May I ask why `decltype(T(array[0]))` and extra pair of braces and parentheses instead of just `std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> { T(array[Is])... }` in the `transform_array_impl` return?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind `why decltype(T(array[0]))` No good reason. I adapted from a piece of code that generated an array from a functor, where that made sense. Fixed now. `extra pair of parentheses` Same as before. `braces` The outer brace is for the `std::array` class template and the inner brace is for the array element within that class. But I suppose that it may be unnecessary due to brace elision rules from C++14.

Comment: understood, thanks, but what about these parentheses: `(T(array[Is]))...` (does it make any difference here vs `T(array[Is])...`?)

Comment: @TheDreamsWind No, it's just a leftover from the code that I adapted from.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the simple solution is to use a `std::vector` instead of an array. Then you can do the initialisation in one line.

```
const std::vector<LetterSet> words(std::begin(DICTIONARY), std::end(DICTIONARY));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do that for an arbitrary variable, but in context of a function template such argument can be built with template recursion:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t Pos = 0, std::size_t Size, typename F, typename ...Elements>
void makeArray(const F(&arr)[Size], const Elements&... elements) {
    if constexpr(Pos < Size) {
        makeArray<T, Pos + 1>(arr, elements..., arr[Pos]);
    } else {
        const T newArray[] { T(elements)... };
        std::cout << sizeof(newArray) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can extend it to a class member, but unfortunately such a recursion doesn't quite work for constructors and you will have to deal with a free function factory (named constructor idiom neither works if you don't want to specify all the template arguments in advance):

```cpp
template<typename Type, std::size_t Size>
class my_class {
    const Type array[Size];
    
    template<typename... Elements>
    my_class(const Elements&... elements): array{ elements... } {}
    
    template<typename T, std::size_t Pos, std::size_t S, typename F, typename ...Elements>
    friend my_class<T, S> makeMyClass(const F(&arr)[S], const Elements&... elements);
    
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Pos = 0, std::size_t S, typename F, typename ...Elements>
my_class<T, S> makeMyClass(const F(&arr)[S], const Elements&... elements) {
    if constexpr(Pos < S) {
        return makeMyClass<T, Pos + 1>(arr, elements..., arr[Pos]);
    } else {
        return my_class<T, S>{ elements... };
    }
}
```

This is how it looks from the client code:

```cpp
int main(){
    
    const char DICTIONARY[][6] = {
        "apple",
        "sands"
    };
    
    const my_class instance = makeMyClass<LetterSet>(DICTIONARY);
    
    return 0;
}
```